# Is there any rhyming word for the word 'month'?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes

I searched but I found that the word 'month' I am looking for, has no perfectly rhyming word. Is it true? Can anyone suggest rhyming words for this word?

I also have certain words like 'millionth'. Is this a suitable match for rhyming with 'month'?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_without_rhymes

Comment: Actually I require some other words except the numerical ones.I was confused for the numerical terms.Thanks for your link.It cleared the confusion but, my search for words rhyming with 'month' continues.

Comment: I think it's General Reference that no "standard" English words rhyme with, for example, *month* and *orange*. But even if you don't already know that, other people are always looking it up, so Google will very quickly lead you to the same web pages they end up finding.

Answer (score 2):

[Wiktionary has these](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes%3aEnglish%3a-%CA%8Cn%CE%B8) listed:

> - en-plus-oneth: (n + 1)th (mathematical term: the ordinal following nth)
> - onety-oneth
> - hundred-and-oneth
> - *Grunth* (probably [Granth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Granth))

If you happen to [have a lisp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes%3aEnglish%3a-%CA%8Cns):

> - dunce
> - once
> - ones

... and so on.

*Millionth* doesn't rhyme perfectly with *month*. But it is reasonably close.

Comment: None of these are accepted standard words. They work in informal contexts though.

Comment: @Mitch _Grunth_ / _Granth_ appears to be.

Comment: Oh. That's a pretty obscure loan word from Hindi.